# How can I implement actions based on my rest API

Tags: java, rest, api, jax-rs

I have a plan of automating a process via REST api and multiple smart devices. What I am trying to do is the following. I have 4 devices that each do a series of actions to complete their task. (practicaly Im gonna be lighting 4 leds in a particular series based on the device). Im currently emulating this in Java (since I dont have the devices at hand)

So for example lets say device no.1 lights up the red led first for 10 seconds,  after that device no.2 needs to light up for 10 seconds etc. That's the task. This is done automatically and forever till I shutdown the program.

I have developed a REST API using JAVA and the JAX-RS library where I state the devices and their info (so device name, current state ex. Yellow Led ON/OFF etc.).

What I dont understand is how I am gonna make the program I have now respond to the info from the API. How can I make my program get notified when a value is changed on the API info?

How can I make device 2 poll the API till it gets the response to start its action? Or make it so it starts the action if i manually change the value on the server data? Example if the yellow led is on, and i go in the server database and put it on off, how will my application get notified and change the state of the simulated led?

Comment: *"How can I make device 2 poll the API"* -- Probably better to use publish/subscribe than polling if your architecture allows it

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont necessarily need to poll, i just want the client (application) to wait till the state changes so it can start the next task

Comment: Right, and as I said, you would "publish" an update event, which the you can "subscribe"  to for a write event to the database and do any other action from there

Comment: Hm I have no clue how I could publish from REST guess I gotta do my homework hehe. Thanx for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using HTTP, most suitable solution is to use **web sockets**. You can use them for full duplex communication. When you receive input from one device, you can process it and inform other devices. Note that this is not suitable for a large client base.